# Multiple elasticsearch match queries

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Say I have a document with 3 text fields: field_a , field_b and field_c.
Is it possible to do a single query so that we have results in this order:

1. 'match' in field_a
2. 'match' in field_b
3. 'match' in field_c

'mutli_match' results can have results from different fields mixed together in the order of the results, what I want is any and all results from field_a, then any and all results from field_b and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though, I find this approach strange in general (I think the problem you have should be solved in a different way, e.g. multiple stages of search), I think you could solve it for now in a following manner.

Multi match query have a perfect ability to [provide boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_fields_literal_and_per_field_boosting) to your fields. E.g.

```
"query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "this is a test",
      "fields" : [ "field_a^1000", "field_b^10", "field_c" ] 
    }
  }
```

The sign `^` is a boost sign which will multiple score of the match in this field by the value - 1000 in case of `field_a`

However, I would recommend to avoid this sort of behavior in general, since:

- It's hard to control those boosting values
- It could be in some cases behaving not as expected (imagine you get the score of 1000 in `field_b`)
- If you would have many hits, this makes whole idea of having match of `field_c` kinda obsolete, since no user will scroll that far away in search results